# OpenGL line segment rasterisation on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, tegra

Let *p<sub>a</sub>* be a point at (0.5, *y*) and *p<sub>b</sub>* at (5.5, *y*). If we draw a line segment from *p<sub>a</sub>* to *p<sub>b</sub>* we get a 5 pixel segment on *x* axis. The question is where exactly these pixels are?

According to the [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification 3.4.1](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf):

> When *p<sub>a</sub>* and *p<sub>b</sub>* lie on fragment centers, this characterization of fragments reduces to Bresenham’s algorithm with one modification: lines produced in this description are “half-open,” meaning that the final fragment (corresponding to *p<sub>b</sub>*) is not drawn.

If we draw a segment from *p<sub>a</sub>* to *p<sub>b</sub>* we get pixels 1 to 5 (*x* coordinate). *p<sub>a</sub>* is on the centre of the first pixel and *p<sub>b</sub>* is on the centre of the 6th one. If we draw from *p<sub>b</sub>* to *p<sub>a</sub>* we get 2 to 6. This is the result I'm getting on iPhone 4s. But on Android (Nexus 7 <s>and emulator</s>) the result is always 1 to 5 (direction doesn't matter). The drawing code is exactly the same (using NDK).

So the question is which behaviour is a correct one? And what workarounds should I use to have the same result on both systems?

**EDIT**

On Mac OS if you run the following code (using simple `NSOpenGLView` subclass):

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.85f, 0.35f);
float pa = 0.5;
float pb = 5.5;
float y =  5.5;
glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -1, 1);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
{
    //pa to pb - lower line
    glVertex3f(pa, y, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(pb, y, 0.0);
    ++y;
    //pb to pa - upper line
    glVertex3f(pb, y, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(pa, y, 0.0);
}
glEnd();
glFlush();
```

You get this result:
[image]

[image: screen shot]

So this is the expected result. And it seems that Nexus 7 has a different interpretation of a spec or I might need to enable some special setting.

**EDIT 2:**

My emulator wasn't fitting into the screen and it was rescaling screen output and it created an illusion that emulator has the same problem as the device. After taking a screenshot through the DDMS it was obvious that emulator produces the expected result: [image: emulator]

But device is producing the following result: [image: nexus_7]

To reproduce this replace the contents of gl_code.cpp file [with the following code](http://pastebin.com/5wpbRupJ) and run *hello-gl2* ndk sample project.

Comment: rasterization depends on the final render target size. Can you confirm you're rendering to a render size that is exactly 100x100 on both the targets?

Comment: also, while I'm at it... can you paste a picture of what you get on the android emulator?

Comment: @Bahbar, please see an updated question. This also has sample code to run and test locally.

Comment: but you haven't confirmed that you're rendering to a 100x100 render target on the actual device. I'm asking because this is _not_ a standard device resolution.

Comment: @Bahabar, only mac sample is 100x100, mobile apps have -w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2 orthographic projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoth the spec you linked to:

> Because the initial and ﬁnal conditions of the diamond-exit rule may
>   be difﬁcult to implement, other line segment rasterization algorithms
>   are allowed, subject to the following rules:
>
> 1. The coordinates of a fragment produced by the algorithm may not deviate by more than one unit in either x or y window coordinates from
>      a corresponding fragment produced by the diamond-exit rule.

Thus, it appears to be a legal deviation, unfortunately.

For workarounds, I'd myself try using coordinates such as 0.25 or 0.75 instead of 0.5 if they might produce the same result on both rasterizers.

Or rasterize a single line in the beginning and see which rule your rasterizer is using and adapt all coordinates later to that.

Comment: I was afraid of such answer :) So your advice is altering the geometry for specific devices?

Comment: Yes, or trying to find a geometry that they would produce the same answer with (e.g., 0.25 instead of 0.5 as the offset might work). And you can test at runtime so you don't have to test with all possible devices...

Comment: I've played with different offsets with no luck. I'm trying to draw a rectangle outline, and always I get a missing pixel at the corner. How would you test at runtime, by rendering to the texture?